# Java Regex: Cannot match angular brackets

Tags: java, regex, escaping

As the title says I cannot match the "<" character in Java 8 regular expressions.

The following expressions all evaluate to false:

`"<hello>".matches("<")`

`"<hello>".matches(Pattern.quote("<"))`

`"<hello>".matches("\\<")`

`"<hello>".matches(Pattern.quote("\\<"))`

How can I escape angular brackets in regular expressions in Java 8?

Comment: Read documentation of `matches()` ...

Comment: Try "<hello>".matches("<.*"). You might want to read about the difference between "matches" and "find"

Answer (score 1):

```
"<hello>".matches("<.*");// => true
```

You need to match wathever comes after => use .*

Comment: Thank you! I forgot you need to match the whole string not just part of it.